# How to activate Windows XP in VMware Player

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, windows-activation

I used a copy of Windows XP that seems to be called "modern.ie" a couple of times in VMware Player, for configuring a USB device that only has XP drivers. The host system is Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

Now, this XP virtual system wants to be activated in order to run. It however does not accept any of the (legal) Windows XP serial numbers that I own. Additionally, when I try to activate over telephone, the voice tells me it can't activate my XP copy also (after I enter the long "Installation ID").

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Thanks for any help how I can manage to run just any copy of XP in VMware Player.

Comment: The installation you are using are only 90 day trials and cannot be activated.  If you want an installation that can be activated that requires you to have Windows XP installation media and install it on the virtual machine yourself.  All the information is literally displayed in the screenshot you provided.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the easiest way to get a working XP in VMware player -- install XP from own installation media over the modern.ie copy? Would that probably give a working XP that can be activated? Or are there other ways?

Comment: Just create a new virtual machine